# Populating an NSArray with Data

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray, nsarray, image-gallery

I want to populate an array after I selected a row. Now I want to populate an array using a function. This is what the situation is. I have a tableview which displays albums titles. When you select a row you show all pictures using the FGallery library. Here is my function for populating my array.

```
- (NSMutableArray *)getAllPicturesOfAlbumId: (int)AlbumId
{
    NSLog(@"tot hier");
    _picturesForAlbum = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSArray *results = [[NSArray alloc]init];
    //picture_Url = @"";
    NSLog(@"tot hier");
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"whichAlbum.album_id == %d", AlbumId];
    [request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Picture" inManagedObjectContext:self.genkDatabase.managedObjectContext]];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSLog(@"tot hier");
    results = [self.genkDatabase.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    if (results == nil) {
        // handle errors
        NSLog(@"geen resultaten");
    } else if (results.count == 0) {
        // nothing found
        NSLog(@"0 resultaten");
    } else {
        for(int i = 0; i < results.count ; i++){
           // NSLog(@"%@",[results valueForKey:@"url"]);
            [_picturesForAlbum addObject: [results valueForKey:@"url"]];
        }
    }

    return _picturesForAlbum;
}
```

Here are my FGallery methods.

```
- (int)numberOfPhotosForPhotoGallery:(FGalleryViewController *)gallery
{
     return [networkImages count];

}


- (FGalleryPhotoSourceType)photoGallery:(FGalleryViewController *)gallery sourceTypeForPhotoAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
     return FGalleryPhotoSourceTypeNetwork;
}


- (NSString*)photoGallery:(FGalleryViewController *)gallery urlForPhotoSize:(FGalleryPhotoSize)size atIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
    return [networkImages objectAtIndex:index];
}
```

And this is what I do in my didSelectRowAtIndexPath

```
networkImages = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[self getAllPicturesOfAlbumId:indexPath.row]];
networkGallery = [[FGalleryViewController alloc] initWithPhotoSource:self];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:networkGallery animated:YES];
```

Put for some reason or another my networkImages is populated several times with the array it gets back from the method "getAllPicturesOfAlbumId"
Because of that I think I get the following error.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa15d090'
```

Anybody has an idea what the problem is?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `[_picturesForAlbum addObject: [results valueForKey:@"url"]];` should be `[_picturesForAlbum addObject: [results[i] valueForKey:@"url"]];` or `[_picturesForAlbum addObject: [[results objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"url"]];` if you have not adopted the new Objective-C syntax yet.

Comment: That exception is caused when an object doesn't recognize the message you sent to it. In this case, it's an array that doesn't recognize the message `length`, which is nowhere in the code snippets you posted; usually, you'd use `count` on an array and `length` on an NSString. Can you double-check where the error is coming from and see if you can pin it down a little further?

Comment: @florian your answer did the trick. But it is always showing me the same picturs. Any idea ?

Comment: `NSLog(@"%@",[results[i] valueForKey:@"url"]);` add this line before the one adding the url to the array and see if it prints the same url. Or better than logging you can set a breakpoint and see what is in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling valueForKey on an array returns an array of all the value for that key. So, in the method getAllPicturesOfAlbumId, you shouldn't loop through results, just return [results valueForKey:@"URL"] (so no need to even create the _picturesForAlbum array).

Comment: Yeah but in my results are also other values. And I only need the values for key url.

Comment: @StefGeelen ' but that's what [results valueForKey] will give you, just the values for that key.

Comment: okay you're right. But it keeps giving me the same pictures. Any idea how that is possible ?

Comment: @StefGeelen, what do you mean by the same pictures? Do you get the same picture no matter which row you select?

Comment: Yes, I always get the pictures of albumId = 1

Comment: @StefGeelen, I don't see how you are passing networkImages to your networkGallery in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method. Also, if you log what you're returning from the getAllPicturesOfAlbumId, does that show the same pictures each time?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18076/discussion-between-stef-geelen-and-rdelmar)